# Kernel task takes about 500% CPU after connecting external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, temperature

I work with macBook Pro (15 Inch 2019, Catalina OS). I can't work with external monitor. 3-5 minutes after pluging in I have kernel_task that takes something about 500-900% CPU. I know there are some similar topics - the main suspect is overheating in such case. I have some changes in temperature, but it's hard to say for me if temperatures are still in ok spot. I have highlighted the biggest changes.              [image: temperatures]

Comment: May I ask what app are you using to read temperature values?

Comment: Istat menus. Some of temperatures are perhaps approximations.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving your charging plug from the left side of the MacBook Pro to the right side. Similarly you can experiment with plugging in the monitor on the other side.

The two sides have different reactions in terms of temperature, so on one side it might not make much difference - and on the other side it could be just above the threshold that triggers an attempt to lower the temperature by making kernel_task occupy the CPU (in idle mode) to save power.

Comment: Ye, I've heard there are some issues with left side charging while working. However I didn't try all possible combinations yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently experienced the same on an older (mid-2015) MacBook Pro, and I think it's a coincidence of (some of) these:

- External monitor connected (if disconnected - `kernel_task` drops)
- Spotlight index broke, and decided to reindex from scratch
- Charger connected
- Sometimes it's `mds_stores` process that hits high CPU if `kernel_task` drops

One thing I find strange with the above numbers is that the CPU is not overheating which normally comes with a high CPU load. However, the entire system becomes sluggish, which makes sense given a background process sucking up most of the CPU.

My take on it all is that the Monterey update had somehow rendered the Spotlight index (`mds_stores` process) useless, and it decided to reindex everything. The external display started fighting for the resources, so indexing would never finish.

My solution was (after resetting PRAM and SMC that didn't help) to disconnect the external display overnight while keeping the power source connected - giving the Spotlight enough room to complete the reindexing.

Next day - Spotlight seems to be done indexing (you can check that by hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and typing anything, the progress bar will appear if indexing is in progress), external display works just fine, system temp is steady below 70 °C, and CPU is stable/idle 90%.